# Multiple columns - HTML

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I have three rows in my html document. The rows look like these:

```
Name: John Smith
DOB: 01/01/1980
Country: Germany
```

I would like to divide each row into two columns, so the output of my document look like this:

```
Name     : John Smith
DOB      : 01/01/1980
Country  : Germany
```

i.e. the `name,dob, and country` identifiers in column one of each row and the `":" and result` in the column 2 of each row.

This is my code so far:

```
   <div>
        <h2>
        <br/>Name: KEY_NAME
        <br/>DOB: KEY_DOB
        <br/>Country: KEY_COUNTRY
        </h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: use p and span tag for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this. Hope it helps. Thanks

```css
div p:first-child{
  
   display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px;
    width: 50px;
  }

span{
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Name </p> <span>:</span> <p>Keyname</p></div>
<div><p>DOB </p> <span>:</span> <p>04/08/93</p></div>
<div><p>Coutry </p> <span>:</span> <p>India</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>john smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DOB</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>10/10/10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>some country</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: you could do the semicolon as its own column or part of the second. Add extra css to taste.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="body" id="contact">
 <form>
  <table>
 <tr>
 <td>Name  :</td><td>John Smith</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>DOB   :</td><td>01/01/1980</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Country:</td><td>Germany</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extra td for colon.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>: john smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DOB</td>
    <td>: 10/10/10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>: some country</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```